# store elements to hashet from file scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, text-files

i am playing a little bit with scala and i want to open a text file, read each line and save some of the fields in a hashset.
The input file will be something like this:

```
1 2 3
2 4 5
```

At first, i am just trying to store the first element of each column to a variable but nothing seems to happen.
My code is:

```
var id = 0
val textFile = sc.textFile(inputFile);
val nline = textFile.map(_.split(" ")).foreach(r => id = r(0))
```

I am using spark because i want to process bigger amount of data later, so i'm trying to get used to it. I am printing id but i get only 0.
  Any ideas?

Comment: If you will have bigger data why would you want it to store in hashset?

Comment: Must read : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

First, inside map and foreach you are running code out on your executors.  The id variable you defined is on the driver.  You can pass variables to your executors using closures, but not the other way around.  If you think about it, when you have 10 executors running through records simultaneously which value of ID would you expect to be returned?

**Edit - foreach is an action**

I mistakenly called foreach not an action below.  It is an action that just lets your run arbitrary code against your rows.  It is useful if you have your own code to save the result to a different data store for example.  foreach does not bring any data back to the driver, so it does not help with your case.

**End edit**

Second, all of the spark methods you called are transformations, you haven't called an action yet.  Spark doesn't actually run any code until an action is called.  Instead it just builds a graph of the transformations you want to happen until you specify an action.  Actions are things that require materializing a result either to provide data back to the driver or save them out somewhere like HDFS.

In your case, to get values back you will want to use an action like "collect" which returns all the values from the RDD back to the driver.  However, you should only do this when you know there aren't going to be many values returned.  If you are operating on 100 million records you do not want to try and pull them all back to the driver!  Generally speaking you will want to only pull data back to the driver after you have processed and reduced it.

Answer (score 0):

> i am just trying to store the first element of each column to a
>   variable but nothing seems to happen.

```
val file_path = "file.txt"
val ds = ss.read.textFile(file_path)

val ar = ds.map(x => x.split(" ")).first()
val (x,y,z) = (ar(0),ar(1),ar(2))
```

You can access the first value of the columns with x,y,z as above.
With your file, x=1, y=2, z=3.

```
val ar1 = ds.map(x => x.split(" "))
val final_ds = ar.select($"value".getItem(0).as("col1") , $"value".getItem(1).as("col2") , $"value".getItem(2).as("col3")) // you can name the columns as like this

Output :
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|
|   2|   4|   5|
+----+----+----+
```

You can run any kind of sql's on `final_ds` like a small sample below.

```
final_ds.select("col1","col2").where(final_ds.col("col1") > 1).show()

Output:
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   2|   4|
+----+----+
```

Comment: that worked but i got the three elements from the first line. What i want is elements from every line. How could i do that?